# Баллон для чата с круглым дизайном внешнего угла

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Я пытаюсь придумать, как сделать внешний закругленный угол  для баллона чата, как  на изображении ниже Вот желаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использовал `bubble` в качестве компонента на другом фоне без одного и того же сплошного цвета, но с некоторым элементом дизайна, поэтому пространство вокруг `bubble` должно быть прозрачным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал добавить элемент как отдельную часть, но это кажется неправильным способом исправить его форму в правильное положение с изменением размера экрана, как отдельной части и чтобы скрыть нижний конец формы за квадратным углом `bubble`:

```css
.balloon {
  margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110);
}

.txt {
  padding: 10px;
}

.right:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -20px;
  border: 12px solid;
  border-color: rgb(114, 238, 110) rgb(114, 238, 110) transparent transparent;
}

.left:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  border: 22px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgb(114, 238, 110);
}

div.selectable div.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -8px;
  width: 37px;
  height: 15px;
  border-right: 8px solid rgb(114, 238, 110);
  border-top: 8px solid rgb(114, 238, 110);
  border-top-right-radius: 39px;
}
```

```html
<div class="balloon right">
  <div class="txt">
    <p>Hello world right side</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="balloon left">
  <div class="txt">
    <p>Hello world left side</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="balloon right">
  <div class="txt">
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
  <div class="selectable">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Outer corner round design balloon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67141551/7394871) от участника  [@iose936](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11137294/iose936).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67141551/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Градиентный фон может это сделать:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) top/100% calc(100% - 34px),
    radial-gradient(105% 100% at bottom left,transparent 97%,green) bottom right/40% 35px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.left {
  background:
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) top/100% calc(100% - 34px),
    radial-gradient(105% 100% at bottom right,transparent 97%,green) bottom left/40% 35px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,lightblue,#f2f2f2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box left">
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67142231/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### SVG

- Контур  `bubble` создан в векторном редакторе
- Тень создана с помощью SVG фильтров `feGaussianBlur` и `feOffset`
- Чтобы приложение было адаптивным `width`и `height` в SVG удалены,
  оставлен только `viewBox`

```css
body {
background: url(https://i.imgur.com/KqppSIN.jpg);
}
.container {
width:25vw;
height:25vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
    <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="6"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>    

 <g filter="url(#shadow)">
<path fill="#72F16E" d="M39 41.5H360.2v82.2H129.7c-60.2 0-90.7 45-90.7 37.3v-36.4z" class="s0"/>
  <path fill="#d3d3d3" d="M360.2 259.5H39v82.2H269.5c60.2 0 90.7 45 90.7 37.3v-36.4z" class="s0"/> 
  
  <text x="95" y="85" font-size="24px" fill="black" > Hello World! </text>  
    <text x="95" y="300" font-size="24px" fill="black" > How are you? </text>  
 </g>   
</svg>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать  `:left` и `:right` с `clip-path` и многоугольником, чтобы создать клип поверх псевдоэлемента.

```css
#chatbox {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbZg0.jpg') no-repeat;
}

.balloon {
  margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110);
}

.txt {
  padding: 10px;
}

.right:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 96% 80%, 91% 63%, 83% 45%, 72% 28%, 56% 15%, 39% 7%, 21% 3%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 96% 80%, 91% 63%, 83% 45%, 72% 28%, 56% 15%, 39% 7%, 21% 3%);
}

.left:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -20px;
  background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 77% 2%, 59% 6%, 42% 13%, 26% 25%, 14% 41%, 8% 59%, 4% 78%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 77% 2%, 59% 6%, 42% 13%, 26% 25%, 14% 41%, 8% 59%, 4% 78%, 0 100%);
}

div.selectable div.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -8px;
  width: 37px;
  height: 15px;
  border-right: 8px solid rgb(114, 238, 110);
  border-top: 8px solid rgb(114, 238, 110);
  border-top-right-radius: 39px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
  <div class="balloon right">
    <div class="txt">
      <p>Hello world right side</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="balloon left">
    <div class="txt">
      <p>Hello world left side</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141798/7394871) от участника  [@dale landry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533592/dale-landry).</sub>